# Execution order in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want when I write something in inputs that are in Parent component the component updated . and I expect order of execution in useEffects of 2 component be this => 1.end child 2.child 3.end parent 4.parent but result is => 1.end child 2.end parent 3.child 4.parent . why result is it?

```
function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container/>
        <Parent/>
      
    </div>
  );
}
function Parent(){
  const [first,setfirst] =useState('');
  const [second,setsecond] =useState('');
  function final(e){
    setsecond(e.target.value);
  }
  function func(e){
    setfirst(e.target.value);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('parent'); //4

    return ()=>{console.log('end parent')} //3
  },[first,second])

  return (
    <>
    <h1>I am parent</h1>
    <input style={{border:"1px solid black"}} value={first} onChange={(e)=>{func(e)}}/>
    <input style={{border:"1px solid black"}} value={second} onChange={(e)=>{final(e)}}/>
    {
      first.length < 7 ? <Testeffect fistargument={first} secondargument={second}/> : <h1>lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
    }
    </>
  )
}

function Testeffect({fistargument,secondargument}){
  
  const [extra,setextra] = useState(0);
  const [force,setforce] =useState(0);
    
  useEffect(()=>{
    
    console.log('child'); //2
     
      return ()=>{console.log('end child')} //1
      
  },[extra,force,fistargument,secondargument])

  return (
    <>
    <h1 onClick={()=>{setextra(extra+1)}}>{fistargument}</h1>
    <h1 onClick={()=>{setforce(force+1)}}>{secondargument}</h1>
    </>
  )
}


export default App;

>
```

Comment: Then it sounds like your expectation is simply incorrect.  Your observations seem to indicate that the effects for the entire render tree are first cleaned up, then as part of re-rendering the tree of components the effects are again invoked, which also sounds like reasonable expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The child component's `useEffect` is being called before the parent component.
In the code example, the parent begins rendering first, followed by the child. The child finishes rendering before the parent, and so its useEffect hook is called first, followed by the parent's. This behaviour is normal.

Yes, there is a way to run effects in the parent, before the child using useLayoutEffect.

**useLayoutEffect :**
`useLayoutEffect` runs synchronously, before the browser has had a chance to paint.

> Like the useEffect Hook, the useLayoutEffect Hook lets you perform
> side effects like API calls, setting up subscriptions, and manually
> manipulating the DOM in a function component.
>
> Although React fires both useEffect and useLayoutEffect after
> performing the DOM updates, useLayoutEffect is called before the
> browser paints those updates for users to see, synchronously, while
> useEffect is called after the browser paints those updates,
> asynchronously.
>
> Therefore, the browser cannot paint any browser updates until
> useLayoutEffect runs. For this reason, you’ll mostly use useEffect,
> which shows your users something like a loader in the browser while
> the side effects are being run.
>
> However, there are a few situations where we want to run the side
> effect and update the DOM before showing our users the updates. We can
> do so using useLayoutEffect with the following syntax.

You can check the entire blog and few coding examples [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/underrated-react-hooks-youre-missing-out-on/)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true, useLayoutEffect is executed on child node first, and then on the parent. The same as useEffect